# How to simplify this logarithm to find the value of x?

Tags: logarithms

$x^{log_2 x} = 2^4$

Solve for x.

How to do this?

Comment: Take $\log_2$ on both sides, for starters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By some easy algebraic computations, we get $x^{\log_2x}=2^{\log_2(x^{\log_2x})}=2^{\log_2x \times \log_2x}=2^{\log_2^2x}$. 
$\Rightarrow \log_2^2x = 4$ 
$\Rightarrow \log_2x = \pm 2$ 
$\Rightarrow x_1 = 2^2 = 4$ and $x_2 = 2^{-2} = \frac{1}{4}$